# How to add Columns in Ext.js within ext.panel.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

[image: my screen]

Im designing a screen in which the header has a button with certain functionality. To acheive this I used

```
Ext.panel.Panel
```

Now I want to add columns within this screen below the header. 
This is my code:

```
var screen = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Search',
    tools: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Click',
        //code here for button functionality
    }],
    layout: 'column',

    items: [{
        text: "column1",
        width: .5
    }, {
        text: "column2",
        width: .5
    }]
})
```

The error Im getting is that I can get the button to work on the header, but cannot see the columns. Is there a solution to fix this?
I have also included the image. The black rectangle shows how my columns are appearing.

Comment: which version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: Change `text` to `title` in columns config. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ervwze4w/1/

Comment: @DevPat Thanks! But now I have all the columns one under the other vertically and not horizontally. Is there a requirement that the width of each column should all add up to 1?

Comment: Yes. There's an example on the [**ExtJs fiddle**](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.layout.container.Column.1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both **Ext 4.1.1** and **Ext 4.2.0** the following changes are required in your code:

1. Rename property `text` to `title` in the columns config
2. In the same config, rename property `width` to `columnWidth`
3. Add `renderTo: Ext.getBody()` attribute

**jsfiddle** seems to impose some limitations on how extjs `panel` is rendered. While I am not sure what's the issue with jsfiddle, here is a [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/UzwBhCAC4a0UuDse24I6?p=preview) that displays `panel` as expected.

IMO, ExtJs GridPanel is a better way to add tool bar to your panel and display tabular data. Read more about it in [Sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel)

Comment: Why not just go and create a [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i8i)?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting @Mr.Polywhirl , I will make a note of it.

Comment: I agree with using ExtJs GridPanel. The columns looked more organized that way, but Im not sure how to get the header button. Im new to Ext so not really sure if I'm going the right way, but so far using panel.Panel seems to be the only way to get it to work.

Comment: use `tbar` configuration for top bar and `fbar` for footer bar. It is done the same way in both Ext.grid.Panel and regular Ext.panel.Panel.

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked out the solution for my question. I needed a button functionality in the header and also columns which could have functionality like arranging the items in ascending/descending order etc (basically the grid.column)

```
var screen = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
title: 'Search',
tools: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Click',
    //code here for button functionality
}],
items:
       [{xtype: 'gridpanel',    
        columns: [
                    {
                    header : "Column 1",
                    width: .5
                    }, 
                    {
                    header : "column2",
                    width: .5
                    }],
                 }],
});
```